# Como pegar um valor de uma frase em String

Tags: android, string

exemplo tenho um retorne desse modo do WebService

> "Sucesso! Usuario salvo. Id: 257"

tudo certo estou pegando a frase como : Sucesso! Usuario salvo. Id: 257

preciso somente pegar o numero ou seja pegar o 257 a frase so serve para confirmar se efetuou a gravação

Meus Código está assim:

```
private void Cadastro(String login, String senha) {
    showProgressDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Const.URL_CADASTRO_USUARIO+"/"+login+"/"+senha, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        //    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
            hideProgressDialog();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [split](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) da classe [String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

Se a frase estiver numa string com o nome Mensagem:

```
String[] partes = Mensagem.split(":");

partes[0]; // terá: Sucesso! Usuario salvo. Id 
partes[1].trim(); // terá: 257
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias formas de realizar esta operação!

Segue um exemplo utilizando [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) e [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

Neste caso, vamos encontrar a posição character `':'` através do método **indexOf** .

Sabendo sua posição, vamos pegar a parte da `String` que nos interessa (do : até o fim) com o **substring**

O método `indexOf` retorna a posição exata então iremos pegar uma casa a frente.

Com o método [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) removemos os espaços em banco:

```
  /*
   * Retorno que iremos trabalhar 
   */
   final String retorno = "Sucesso! Usuario salvo. Id: 257";

   // Pegamos a posição do : na String
   int posicaoDoisPontos = retorno.indexOf(':');

   // Caso ão ache os : na STring irá retornar -1
   if(posicaoDoisPontos > -1){
         // Vamos pegar a psoição a frente do : até o fim da String (seu tamanho)
         String idLiteral =  retorno.substring( (posicaoDoisPontos+1) , retorno.length() );
         // Transformamos a String em Integer
         Integer id = Integer.valueOf(idLiteral.trim());
         System.out.println(id);
    }else{
          System.out.println("Não foi possível formatar o valor!");
     }
```

[Veja o código rodando no Ideone!](http://ideone.com/Hf8xK4)